# Sum of digits program, Getting wrong answer

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have used querystring to accept number in my classic asp code, and then the program will output the sum of digits of the number.

```
<%
dim n,d,sum
sum = 0
d = 0
n = request.querystring("n")  //Taking value from querystring
while n<>0
d = n mod 10
response.write("<br>"&d)
sum = sum + d``
n = Cint(n/10)
wend
response.write("<br>Sum of digits of "&request.querystring("n")&" is : 
"&sum)
%>
```

But the problem is it does not show correct answers for few values like 
for eg. n=91....then output will be 11
but for n=123...the output will be 6.
pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only have to do one change in the code** , i.e. use the operator **\** instead of **/**
when you reduce your number....

i.e. instead of **n = CInt(n/10)** use **n = n\10**

Therefore the code will work fine as butter:

```
<%
dim n,sum,d
sum = 0
n = request.querystring("n")    'taking value from querystring

while n <> 0
d = n mod 10
sum = sum +d
n = n\10                       'using \ for integer division
wend
response.write("Sum of digits of : "&request.querystring("n")&" is = "&sum)
%>
```

For those who dont understand what just happened see below:

1. Operator **/** : Performs a floating division.
2. Operator **\** : Performs a Integer division.

Thats why I was not getting correct results. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to treat n as a string, which is really a character array.  Because a string is a character array we can loop through the array and sum each value.

```
Dim n, d, sum
sum = 0
d = 0
n = Request.QueryString("n")
If IsNumeric(n) Then
    For i = 1 To Len(n)
        d = CInt(Mid(n,i,1))
        Response.Write("<br />" & d)
        sum = sum + d
    Next
    Response.Write("<br />Sum of digits of " & n & " is : " & sum)
End If
```

Comment: Good answer. Can comments start with // in classic asp or must they start with ' ?

Comment: Only `'` for comments with VBScript; however, you can use JavaScript as a language with Classic ASP.

Comment: Thankyou so much dude..you are awesome!

Comment: @ThatGuyInIT actually you can't use JavaScript that is a common misconception. You can use JScript though which is an Active Scripting language developed by Microsoft and based off an older version of ECMAScript.